# How to solve $\lim\limits_{z\to i} \frac{1}{n!}(\frac{1}{dz})^n(z-i)^{n+1}e^{-iz\eta}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{(z-i)^{k+1}}(2i)^k $?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Let $\eta<0$. I need help to calculate the limit 
$$\lim\limits_{z\to i} \frac{1}{n!}(\frac{1}{dz})^n(z-i)^{n+1}e^{-iz\eta}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{(z-i)^{k+1}}(2i)^k .$$ The solution should be $$e^{\eta}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(-i\eta )^k}{k!}\binom{n}{k} (2i)^k .$$ My first steps:

$\lim\limits_{z\to i} \frac{1}{n!}(\frac{1}{dz})^n(z-i)^{n+1}e^{-iz\eta}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{(z-i)^{k+1}}(2i)^k =\lim\limits_{z\to i} \frac{1}{n!}(\frac{1}{dz})^n e^{-iz\eta}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{(z-i)^{k-n}}(2i)^k 
=\lim\limits_{z\to i} \frac{1}{n!}(\frac{1}{dz})^n e^{\eta}e^{-i\eta(z-i)}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{(z-i)^{k-n}}(2i)^k=e^{\eta}\lim\limits_{z\to i} \frac{1}{n!}(\frac{1}{dz})^n \sum\limits_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-i\eta)^l}{l!}(z-i)^{l+1}. \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{(z-i)^{k-n}}(2i)^k$. Maybe we can swap the derivative in theseries later, because the exp-series converges absolutely on $\mathbb{C}$. But I don't know how to continue or how to calculate the limit in detail. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you mean $\left(\frac1{dx}\right)^n$ or $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^n$?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that $\left(\frac1{dz}\right)^n$ means $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\right)^n$.

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac1{(z-i)^{k+1}}(2i)^k
&=\frac1{z-i}\left(1+\frac{2i}{z-i}\right)^n\\
&=\frac{(z+i)^n}{(z-i)^{n+1}}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, [Leibniz's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) says
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac1{n!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}z^n}\left[(z-i)^{n+1}e^{-iz\eta}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac1{(z-i)^{k+1}}(2i)^k\right]\\
&=\frac1{n!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}z^n}\left[e^{-iz\eta}(z+i)^n\vphantom{\sum_0^1}\right]\\
&=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\underbrace{(-i\eta)^ke^{-iz\eta}\vphantom{\frac{n!}{k!}}}_{\substack{\text{$k$ derivatives}\\\text{of $e^{-iz\eta}$}}}\underbrace{\frac{n!}{k!}(z+i)^k}_{\substack{\text{$n-k$ derivatives}\\\text{of $(z+i)^n$}}}
\end{align}
$$
Set $z=i$ to get
$$
e^\eta\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(2\eta)^k}{k!}
$$